# Conectarme a base de datos Oracle desde Vim

Tags: oracle, vim

Estoy usando el plugin DBext para realizar consultas sql desde vim, para MySQL funciona perfecto, pero cuando quiero usar Oracle no me deja conectarme, me sale el siguiente error.

```
Connection: T(ORA)  S(//localhost:1521/XE)  U(hr)   at 11:44
1 job started:11:44:11 updates every 2000 ms                                                                                                                             
2 ERROR:
3 ORA-12541: TNS:no hay ning<fa>n listener                                                                              
4 SP2-0751: No se ha podido conectar a Oracle. Saliendo de SQL*Plus
```

He probado las siguientes cadenas de conexión en el .vimrc segun el archivo de ayuda de DBext pero ninguna me funciona

```
let g:dbext_default_profile_myORA = 'type=ORA:srvname=127.0.0.1\:1521/XE:user=EJEMPLO:passwd=123'
let g:dbext_default_profile_ORA_URL = 'type=ORA:srvname=//localhost\:1521/XE:user=hr:passwd=hr'
let g:dbext_default_profile_ORA_Extended_DBI = 'type=DBI:user=hr:passwd=hr:driver=Oracle:conn_parms=SID=xe;HOST=localhost;PORT=1521'
let g:dbext_default_profile_ORA_Extended = 'type=ORA:user=hr:passwd=hr:srvname=(description=(address=(protocol=TCP)(host=127.0.0.1)(port=1521)))'
```

Comment: `ORA-12541: TNS:no hay ning<fa>n listener ` me lleva a preguntar: estás seguro que se está ejecutando el servicio en el puerto que esperas? Tu configuración parece estar intentando la conexión pero no encuentra nada en la ip y puerto indicados.

Comment: @Alfabravo Si, el servicio está iniciado, pero estaba probando conectarme desde el sql developer pero tampoco me está dejando, al parecer no es problema de la conexión si no del servicio.